# Sort by 2nd-level computed relationship in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
var projectSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: ObjectId, required: true, index: true, ref: 'user' },
    title: { type: String }
}, { versionKey: false });

var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
}, { versionKey: false });

var ratingSchema = new Schema({
    source_user: { type: ObjectId, required: true, index: true, ref: 'user' },
    destination_user: { type: ObjectId, required: true, index: true, ref: 'user' },
    vote: { type: String, required: true, enum: ['positive', 'negative'] }
}, { versionKey: false });
```

I want to get a list of projects ordered by the rating of the user owning the project. The rating is computed as `positive_ratings / total_ratings`.

I was able to calculate the rating in Mongo with:

```
db.getCollection('ratings').group({
    key: { destination_user: true },
    reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.total_feedback += 1; if(obj.vote == 'positive') prev.positive_feedback += 1; prev.feedback = prev.positive_feedback / prev.total_feedback; },
    initial: { total_feedback: 0, positive_feedback: 0, feedback: 0 }
})
```

But I need the projects, so I have to do it in Mongoose, cause Mongo doesn't know relationships.

In SQL this would be easy, but I'm not that good at NoSQL. Is something like this possible?

Comment: I would be simple in MongoDB if you simply stored the related data you need directly within the ratings. That is the whole purpose of NoSQL, where you forgo the relational form principles and just store the data how you intend to access it. If not all then at least the properties you know you are going to want to use. Also look at [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) in general, as `.group()` is an old and hacky poor cousin to what was basically intended to replace it.

Comment: Oh and "mongoose does not know relationships either". You are believing a lie. All mongoose does with things like `.populate()` is basically another query to the other collection using `$in`. This is not a join, it's another query and trip to the database.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I understand, but that would mean that I save my ratings on the `project` scheme, right? But that's not good design, because ratings have to do with the user, not with the project, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you need to explain which properties from which related collections are important to your aggregation operation and the sorting process. Then it becomes a bit more clear how to model for your purposes. But really you need to explain or at least consider all of your data usage. You are making the common mistake of using a NoSQL datastore but hanging on to your relational principles. You either need the NoSQL advantage or you do not. If so then you need to model to "exploit" it rather than hinder it.